# R - gsub only digits

Tags: regex, r, gsub, grepl

I would like to clean this vector and only retain the digits

```
vec = c(" 4010  \"Filling in time budget diary\"", " 8888  \"Prob cont. preceding activity\"", " 9999   \"Missing, undecipherable\";")
```

what I would like is simply : `4010, 8888, 9999`

I thought of something like, matching exactly the digits but it doesn't work.

```
gsub("^[[:digit:]]$", replacement = '', vec)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can use `\\D+` to match all non-numeric elements and replace with `''`

```
 gsub('\\D+','', vec)
```

Comment: oh very nice, what is the  `+` means ?

Comment: @giacomoV  It means one or more non-numeric elements.

Comment: @giacomoV Or another option is `library(stringr); str_extract_all(vec, '\\d+')`